# How to get data from date 15th to 15th

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table of user's input times as follows :

table name is timebilling :

fields :

```
 TimeBillingId  int
 UserId         int
 StartTime      datetime
 StopTime       datetime
 ElapsedTime    time(7)
 NormalTime     time(7)
 OverTime       time(7)
```

Now i want to a report in which i want to calculate total times of all users. Like Total ElapsedTime, total normaltime and total overtime by month.

But my month is 15th to 15th. So i want results should be like this :

```
User    Month        TotalTime         NormalTime       OverTime
 1     March-April   120:58:00         100:58:00        20:00:00
 2     March-April    97:40:23          97:40:23        00:00:00
 1     April-May      15:00:00          14:30:00        00:30:00
 2     April-May      89:30:00          80:15:00        09:15:00
```

I am using this query to get it working by month to month :

```
select MONTH(tym.StopTIme) as Month, YEAR(tym.StopTime) as Year, U.UserId,
ISNULL((select cast(sum(datediff(second,0,t.ElapsedTime))/3600 as varchar(20)) + ':' + right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,t.ElapsedTime))/60%60 as varchar(20)),2) + ':' + right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,t.ElapsedTime))%60 as varchar(20)),2) 
from TimeBilling t where MONTH(t.StopTime) = MONTH(tym.StopTime) and YEAR(t.StopTime) = YEAR(tym.StopTime) and t.UserId = u.UserId),'00:00:00') as TotalTime,

ISNULL((select cast(sum(datediff(second,0,t.NormalTime))/3600 as varchar(20)) + ':' + right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,t.NormalTime))/60%60 as varchar(20)),2) + ':' + right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,t.NormalTime))%60 as varchar(20)),2) 
from TimeBilling t where MONTH(t.StopTime) = MONTH(tym.StopTime) and YEAR(t.StopTime) = YEAR(tym.StopTime) and t.UserId = u.UserId),'00:00:00') as NormalTime,

ISNULL((select cast(sum(datediff(second,0,t.OverTime))/3600 as varchar(20)) + ':' + right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,t.OverTime))/60%60 as varchar(20)),2) + ':' + right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,t.OverTime))%60 as varchar(20)),2) 
from TimeBilling t where MONTH(t.StopTime) = MONTH(tym.StopTime) and YEAR(t.StopTime) = YEAR(tym.StopTime) and t.UserId = u.UserId),'00:00:00') as OverTime 
from TimeBilling tym, Users u
where tym.UserId = u.UserId
```

I got the totaltime by month to month like 1st to 30th/31st. But i want to get from 15th to 15th. but i don't know how to get it in sql query or stored procedure.

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID, Month, SUM(...) AS TotalTime, SUM(...) AS TotalNormalTime....
FROM
(
SELECT
T.*, 
CASE WHEN DAY(StartTime) > 15 THEN DateName(month, StartTime) + '-' + DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, 1, StartTime))
ELSE DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, -1, StartTime)) + '-' +  DateName(month, StartTime)
END AS Month
FROM TimeBilling T
) TX
GROUP BY UserID, Month
```

Comment: Thanks Anup. The from clause helped me. I will change my query condition accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is just to subtract 14 days from the date and group by that.  I am going to assume that you already know how to aggregate the times:

```
select UserId,
       datename(month, min(starttime - 14)),
from timebilling tb
group by UserID, year(starttime - 14), month(starttime - 14)
```

This would produce the first month in the sequence.  If you want both months:

```
select UserId,
       datename(month, min(starttime - 14)) + '-' + datename(month, dateadd(month, 1, min(starttime - 14)))
from timebilling tb
group by UserID, year(starttime - 14), month(starttime - 14)
```

Comment: How to calculate time for this 15th to 15th month ? I know how to sum the time values. but i dont know how to get time records from 15th to 15th.

Comment: @Mausami . . . Subtracting 14 days puts the dates in the same month.  That is what this query does.  For aggregation purposes, the 15th becomes the 1st, the 16th the 2nd.  For the next month, the 14th becomes the last day of the previous month.  And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use a calendar table:

http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html

An alternative method could be constructed using DatePart and DateName like so:

```
DECLARE @dt DATE = '20130411'
--GETDATE() 

;
WITH    c AS ( SELECT   enddate = DATEADD(MONTH,
                                          CASE WHEN DAY(@dt) >= 16 THEN 1
                                               ELSE 0
                                          END,
                                          DATEADD(MONTH,
                                                  DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @dt), 0))
             )
    SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, enddate)) + '-'
            + DATENAME(MONTH, enddate)
    FROM    c
```

Comment: can i do it with query ? because i need to develop a report of it.

Comment: I want to do it by sql query or stored procedure.

Comment: this method is working correctly to get the month. but i need to have all months from april 2013 to current month. and i want to calculate totaltime also for that month range.